# High Pings On New Internet Provider

Tags: networking, internet

I am new to setting up routers and networks, so I am unsure. I still have everything to the factory settings. My net connection is quite slow, and seems unreasonably so even when connected with wired. Though on wireless I get ping results like this:

```
PING google.com (72.14.204.147) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from iad04s01-in-f147.1e100.net (72.14.204.147): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=921 ms  
64 bytes from iad04s01-in-f147.1e100.net (72.14.204.147): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=1024 ms  
64 bytes from iad04s01-in-f147.1e100.net (72.14.204.147): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=1038 ms  

--- google.com ping statistics ---  
4 packets transmitted, 3 received, 25% packet loss, time 4047ms  
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 921.235/994.828/1038.661/52.354 ms, pipe 2
```

I have Verizon DSL if that matters. Thanks for any help in advance! ^_^

Answer (score 5):

In order to narrow down the problem use the *traceroute* command. This works similarly to ping but tries to measure the time it takes to reach each step (router) between you and the target site.

For example the following shows the output from traceroute from my desktop to google. The three times shown at the right of the line are the times taken to reach each step. You will likely see a big jump between two lines and this will give you a hint where the problem lies. In most cases you will only have control over the first (or maybe 2nd step) if the jump is after that then the problem likely lies with your ISP.

```
richm@royalcounty:~$ traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (173.194.37.104), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.253 (192.168.1.253)  0.932 ms  1.821 ms  2.451 ms
 2  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  18.140 ms  18.375 ms  18.585 ms
 3  lo98.sc-acc-sip-1.as9105.net (212.74.102.14)  49.461 ms  50.571 ms  51.492 ms
 4  10.72.4.66 (10.72.4.66)  53.092 ms  55.379 ms  55.534 ms
 5  10.72.9.217 (10.72.9.217)  56.417 ms  57.158 ms  58.020 ms
 6  xe-8-3-0.bragg001.log.as13285.net (80.40.155.33)  59.461 ms  58.231 ms  58.912 ms
 7  xe-7-3-0.scr001.log.as13285.net (80.40.155.52)  67.517 ms  52.667 ms  53.769 ms
 8  xe-10-2-0-scr010.thn.as13285.net (78.144.1.2)  51.251 ms  48.155 ms xe-11-0-0-scr010.thn.as13285.net (78.144.1.0)  48.980 ms
 9  host-78-144-3-30.as13285.net (78.144.3.30)  58.058 ms  58.216 ms  58.313 ms
10  64.233.175.27 (64.233.175.27)  53.913 ms  54.135 ms  55.319 ms
11  209.85.251.202 (209.85.251.202)  64.648 ms  64.875 ms  65.158 ms
12  lhr14s02-in-f104.1e100.net (173.194.37.104)  59.522 ms  59.695 ms  62.261 ms
```

I'm not sure if traceroute is installed by default in Ubuntu. If it is not installed then you can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install traceroute
```

Comment: traceroute to www.google.com (72.14.204.99), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  . (192.168.2.1)  3.926 ms  6.284 ms  15.806 ms
 2  dslrouter.westell.com (192.168.1.1)  15.786 ms  15.773 ms  15.755 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *

Comment: That does not seem right. :(

Comment: The "*" output is because traceroute is not receiving a response at each individual hop level. This is typically because ISPs block the network packets that traceroute uses to probe the network. You could try using mtr (sudo apt-get install mtr-tiny) and see if that gives you any different results. Just run it using the command "mtr". I have sometimes found that mtr can give results where traceroute fails.

Comment: If mtr does not give you any luck you could try using "traceroute -U www.google.com" or "mtr -u www.google.com". The -U/-u command causes the program to use UDP datagrams rather than ICMP echo (ping) packets to probe the network.